# How do you calculate the norm of a function describing a molecular orbital?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

I'm a bit confused by a past paper question I came across for one of my courses, shown below.

> The wavefunctions corresponding to the lowest, $\psi_{1}$, and second-lowest, $\psi_{2}$, energy molecular orbitals in 1,3-butadiene are:
>   $$\psi_{1}=0.372\phi_{1} + 0.602\phi_{2}+0.602\phi_{3} +0.372\phi_{4}$$
>   $$\psi_{2}=0.602\phi_{1} + 0.372\phi_{2}-0.372\phi_{3} -0.602\phi_{4}$$
>   where $\phi_{i}$ is the $p_{z}$ orbital on atom $i$. Calculate the norm of $\psi_{1}$, and the overlap between $\psi_{1}$ and $\psi_{2}$. Is the result what you would expect? Explain.

Neither calculating norm nor the overlap between 2 orbitals in the way the question asks came up.
I assume by norm it means the normalisationg factor, but that makes no sense to me since it's already normalised. I assume the overlap should be 0 since they should be orthonormal, but don't know how to show that. I'd really appreciate some help!
Sadly the lecturer for the course has contracted Covid-19 and so of course is not available to answer questions.

Comment: A screenshot or picture of an exercise is not searchable. Please consider rewriting it, so that it can be of help for future visitors.

Comment: Please add a citation to where this exercise comes from. Also note that the use $\psi_x$ in the text and $\Psi_x$ in the equation. They should be the same, and should probably be all lower-case.

Comment: The "norm" refers to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm.

Comment: As I stated in my question, it comes from a past paper at my university. I take your point about the notation; that's simply how the question is in the exam paper.

Comment: if the $\phi$ are orthonormal then $\langle \phi_i\phi_j\rangle = \delta_{i,j} $ meaning that if $i=j$ the result is 1 else it is zero. So multiply out term by term to get overlap $\langle \psi_1\psi_2\rangle$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm unsure if you're meant to solve this via the Hückel molecular orbital theory (see [Chemistry LibreTexts](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Pacific_Union_College/Quantum_Chemistry/10%3A_Bonding_in_Polyatomic_Molecules/10.06%3A_Butadiene_is_Stabilized_by_a_Delocalization_Energy)), however, if you need to calculate the *norm* of a wave function $\Psi$, this is $|\Psi |$. Given what we know in your post about both $\Psi_{1, 2}$ then
\begin{align}
  |\Psi_1|^2 
    &= \langle\Psi_1 | \Psi_1\rangle \\
    &= 2\cdot(0.602^2)+2 \cdot (0.372^2) \\
    &= 1.001576 \\
  \to |\Psi_1| &= 1.000788 > 1\\
\end{align}
I write that this is greater than one, as, on closer inspection,  is down to rounding from the coefficients of each $p_z$ orbital.

The repeat process can be found for the overlap part, which I am interpreting as $\langle\Psi_1 | \Psi_2\rangle$.

Comment: Yes, we did cover Huckel in this course. I suspect that the fact that it's greater than 1 is a rounding error rather than intentional. 
Thank you - that's really useful

Comment: Great I'm glad to have helped, in terms of thr rounding, you may have a point actually, looking at various other Wave functions for the Energy bounds of 1,3-Butadiene I see close enough numbers that do indeed sum-square to unity.

Comment: @Martin mod - thanks for the improvment in my Bar-Ket notation.

Comment: Happy to help. MathJax (i.e. Latex syntax) is not the most intuitive. There are some guides on our meta, if you want to learn more.